# AFNetwork , I have something confused

Tags: uiimageview, afnetworking

```
@implementation UIImageView (AFNetworking)
```

has a method

```
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError *error))failure
```

In the implementation of this method, the active request URL is compared to the `urlRequest` parameter:

```
if ([self isActiveTaskURLEqualToURLRequest:urlRequest]){
    return;
}
```

When is this condition true?

I thought so much time, but have no idea, how does it work?
mostly always NO, when can be YES? for example?

Comment: I need your help, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of `isActiveTaskURLEqualToURLRequest:` method checks to see if there is already an active task downloading the image from the same URL. It returns `TRUE` when the method is called with the same `urlRequest` parameter before the image download task has completed. The check is there to prevent duplicate image downloads for the same UIImageView.

For example, if you were to call this method twice in succession in the same code block with the same NSURLRequest parameter, the first time the check is made, the `if` will evaluate to `FALSE` because it doesn't have an active task (one will be created and executed). The second time the check is made, the `if` will evaluate to `TRUE` because there is already an active task downloading the image.

To see for yourself, copy this call, then paste it as the next statement. Set a breakpoint on the second (duplicate) call and step through.